# POST Tweets from different Accounts in Android App

Tags: android

every one. I have made an application in android which post tweets on twitter, But problem is it only post tweets of my account of which I have provided "Consumer key", "Consumer secret",  "oauth_token" and "oauth_token_secret".
But I want that my app should ask for login to the user( if he is not logged in already), take his tweet in editText and post to twitter. What should i do? Any help is highly appreciated.

I am using these field in my previous app.

```
Creating the Consumer and Access KEy web:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/tokens-devtwittercom

Consumer key            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Consumer secret     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Request token URL   https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token
Authorize URL   https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize
Access token URL    https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token
Callback URL    None

Access token               xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Access token secret    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Access level    Read-only
```

Code:
OathRequestTokenTask.java

```
package com.nxb.twitter;

import com.nxb.twitter.preferences.Constants;

import oauth.signpost.OAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.OAuthProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * An asynchronous task that communicates with Twitter to 
 * retrieve a request token.
 * (OAuthGetRequestToken)
 * 
 * After receiving the request token from Twitter, 
 * pop a browser to the user to authorize the Request Token.
 * (OAuthAuthorizeToken)
 * 
 */
public class OAuthRequestTokenTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    final String TAG = getClass().getName();
    private Context context;
    private OAuthProvider provider;
    private OAuthConsumer consumer;

    /**
     * 
     * We pass the OAuth consumer and provider.
     * 
     * @param   context
     *          Required to be able to start the intent to launch the browser.
     * @param   provider
     *          The OAuthProvider object
     * @param   consumer
     *          The OAuthConsumer object
     */
    public OAuthRequestTokenTask(Context context,OAuthConsumer consumer,OAuthProvider provider) {
        this.context = context;
        this.consumer = consumer;
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Retrieve the OAuth Request Token and present a browser to the user to authorize the token.
     * 
     */
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            Log.i(TAG, "Retrieving request token from Google servers");
            final String url = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer, Constants.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);
            Log.i(TAG, "Popping a browser with the authorize URL : " + url);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error during OAUth retrieve request token", e);
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

PrepareTokenRequestActivity.java

```
package com.nxb.twitter;
import com.nxb.twitter.preferences.Constants;
import com.nxb.twitter.utils.TwitterUtils;

import oauth.signpost.OAuth;
import oauth.signpost.OAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.OAuthProvider;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthProvider;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Prepares a OAuthConsumer and OAuthProvider 
 * 
 * OAuthConsumer is configured with the consumer key & consumer secret.
 * OAuthProvider is configured with the 3 OAuth endpoints.
 * 
 * Execute the OAuthRequestTokenTask to retrieve the request, and authorize the request.
 * 
 * After the request is authorized, a callback is made here.
 * 
 */
public class PrepareRequestTokenActivity extends Activity {

    final String TAG = getClass().getName();

    private OAuthConsumer consumer; 
    private OAuthProvider provider;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            this.consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
            this.provider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider(Constants.REQUEST_URL,Constants.ACCESS_URL,Constants.AUTHORIZE_URL);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error creating consumer / provider",e);
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "Starting task to retrieve request token.");
        new OAuthRequestTokenTask(this,consumer,provider).execute();
    }

    /**
     * Called when the OAuthRequestTokenTask finishes (user has authorized the request token).
     * The callback URL will be intercepted here.
     */
    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent); 
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        final Uri uri = intent.getData();
        if (uri != null && uri.getScheme().equals(Constants.OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Callback received : " + uri);
            Log.i(TAG, "Retrieving Access Token");
            new RetrieveAccessTokenTask(this,consumer,provider,prefs).execute(uri);
            finish();   
        }
    }

    public class RetrieveAccessTokenTask extends AsyncTask<Uri, Void, Void> {

        private Context context;
        private OAuthProvider provider;
        private OAuthConsumer consumer;
        private SharedPreferences prefs;

        public RetrieveAccessTokenTask(Context context, OAuthConsumer consumer,OAuthProvider provider, SharedPreferences prefs) {
            this.context = context;
            this.consumer = consumer;
            this.provider = provider;
            this.prefs=prefs;
        }


        /**
         * Retrieve the oauth_verifier, and store the oauth and oauth_token_secret 
         * for future API calls.
         */
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Uri...params) {
            final Uri uri = params[0];
            final String oauth_verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER);

            try {
                provider.retrieveAccessToken(consumer, oauth_verifier);

                final Editor edit = prefs.edit();
                edit.putString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, consumer.getToken());
                edit.putString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, consumer.getTokenSecret());
                edit.commit();

                String token = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
                String secret = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, "");

                consumer.setTokenWithSecret(token, secret);
                context.startActivity(new Intent(context,TwitterIntegrationActivity.class));

                executeAfterAccessTokenRetrieval();

                Log.i(TAG, "OAuth - Access Token Retrieved");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "OAuth - Access Token Retrieval Error", e);
            }

            return null;
        }


        private void executeAfterAccessTokenRetrieval() {
            String msg = getIntent().getExtras().getString("tweet_msg");
            try {
                TwitterUtils.sendTweet(prefs, msg);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "OAuth - Error sending to Twitter", e);
            }
        }
    }   

}
```

TwitterIntegrationActivity.java

```
package com.nxb.twitter;
import java.util.Date;

import oauth.signpost.OAuth;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.nxb.twitter.utils.TwitterUtils;

public class TwitterIntegrationActivity extends Activity {

    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private final Handler mTwitterHandler = new Handler();
    private TextView loginStatus;
private EditText status;
    final Runnable mUpdateTwitterNotification = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Tweet sent !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        this.prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        loginStatus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.login_status);
        status=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textStatus);
        Button tweet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_tweet);
        Button clearCredentials = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_clear_credentials);

        tweet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            /**
             * Send a tweet. If the user hasn't authenticated to Tweeter yet, he'll be redirected via a browser
             * to the twitter login page. Once the user authenticated, he'll authorize the Android application to send
             * tweets on the users behalf.
             */
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated(prefs)) {
                    sendTweet();
                } else {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PrepareRequestTokenActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("tweet_msg",getTweetMsg());
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        });

        clearCredentials.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clearCredentials();
                updateLoginStatus();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        updateLoginStatus();
    }

    public void updateLoginStatus() {
        loginStatus.setText("Logged into Twitter : " + TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated(prefs));
    }


    private String getTweetMsg() {
        return status.getText().toString().trim()+"   "+ new Date().toLocaleString();
    }   

    public void sendTweet() {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                try {
                    TwitterUtils.sendTweet(prefs,getTweetMsg());
                    mTwitterHandler.post(mUpdateTwitterNotification);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        };
        t.start();
    }

    private void clearCredentials() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        final Editor edit = prefs.edit();
        edit.remove(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN);
        edit.remove(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET);
        edit.commit();
    }
}
```

Constants.java

```
package com.nxb.twitter.preferences;

public class Constants {
    public static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    public static final String CONSUMER_SECRET ="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

    public static final String OATH_TOKEN="4XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    public static final String OATH_TOKEN_SECRET="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

    public static final String REQUEST_URL = "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";
    public static final String ACCESS_URL = "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token";
    public static final String AUTHORIZE_URL = "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize";

    public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME = "x-oauthflow-twitter";
    public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST = "callback";
    public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL = OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME
            + "://" + OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST;
}
```

TwitterUtils.java

```
package com.nxb.twitter.utils;

import com.nxb.twitter.preferences.Constants;

import oauth.signpost.OAuth;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.http.AccessToken;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class TwitterUtils {

    public static boolean isAuthenticated(SharedPreferences prefs) {

//      String token = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
//      String secret = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, "");
        String token =Constants.OATH_TOKEN;
        String secret =Constants.OATH_TOKEN_SECRET;


        AccessToken a = new AccessToken(token,secret);
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        twitter.setOAuthConsumer(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
        twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);

        try {
            twitter.getAccountSettings();
            return true;
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void sendTweet(SharedPreferences prefs,String msg) throws Exception {
//      String token = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
//      String secret = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, "");
        String token =Constants.OATH_TOKEN;
        String secret =Constants.OATH_TOKEN_SECRET;

        AccessToken a = new AccessToken(token,secret);
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        twitter.setOAuthConsumer(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
        twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);
        twitter.updateStatus(msg);
    }   
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/login_status"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/labeleWhatisHappening"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textStatus"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:background="@color/transparentBlue"
        android:hint="@string/hintStatus"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:maxLength="160"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:textColor="#E6E6E6"
        android:textColorHint="#E6E6E6" >
    </EditText>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_tweet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tweet" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_clear_credentials"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Clear Credentials" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post ur code that u r using to post tweets

Comment: SeshuVinay  code posted.....Now please review it!